# Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project

Tags: installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a setup project that I need to install a redistributable that is not available in the default prerequisite list.  Is it possible to add this redistributable to the bootstrapper that the setup project creates?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I figured out how to add Custom Prerequisites to the Visual Studio prerequisites dialog box.
[MSDN as a good article on creating the prerequisite.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx) 
Basically you just have to create a product manifest and a package manifest, copy them along with your distributable file to : \Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages.  Visual studio will automatically pick it up.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at Bootstrapper Manifest Generator tool (BMG) at *http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg*

It is used for creating Bootstrapper packages and automatically adding them to Visual Studio's Prerequisites dialog box.

Edit: BMG can be downloaded from https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Bootstrapper-Manifest-Generator.shtml now since the tool is deprecated apparently and is no longer located on Microsoft servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: [this](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Bootstrapper-Manifest-Generator.shtml) seems the last location where the BMG is available. That tool is old and deprecated by MS, which now "suggests" to create the package by hand, as @Web says in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by creating Custom bootstrapper package.Following link provides creation of it with a sample example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee726596.aspx