# Adding SQL Server Express Edition SP3 as Project Requirement

Tags: visual-studio, installation, sql-server-express

I'm deploying my Web project and in the requirements I mention that I need SQL Express Edition SP2 (x86) as you can see by the picture below

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-25_1107.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-25_1107.png)

Problem is when the client has already Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition SP3 (this on a **64 bit** machine)

when we try to install I get this error

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-25_1111.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-25_1111.png)

Questions:

- even thought I tell my Setup that client machine has to have SQL 2005 SP2 (x86), shouldn't it see that it already have a newer version, even thought it's 64bit?
- How can I **add SQL Express edition SP3** to the list of prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom prerrequisite to detect the presence of SQL Express SP2 or later, instead of specifically SP2, and add it to your install project. See here: [Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project).