# Deployment Package to run multiple windows installers

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

I am using VS2010 and I have written a .NET application in C# that is dependant on two other third-party drivers that need to be installed on the computer as well. I have created a setup and deployment program for my application, but I would like it to also run the installers for the drivers as well. I have been tinkering with adding Launch Conditions, but so far I have had no luck. Does anyone have any idea how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with prerequisites. Here is a similar thread:

[Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project)