# Package a installer for my application

Tags: .net, installation, package

I want to package my application to installer. I use .NET Framework 3.5 & Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for my application. I can attach .NET Framework & VS J# 2.0 into my package. When running installer, installer can detect the present of .NET Framework & VS J#. If they are not existing, installer ask the user to install them before.

Please help me the way to deploy this installer. I can use availaible features in Visual Studio 2010 or must using a third-party application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thread which may help you add your prerequisites:

[Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project)

If this doesn't help, can you please give us more details about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Visual Studio Installer, you could try [InstallJammer](http://installjammer.com/) and see [this thread](http://www.installjammer.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=906) for information regarding checking for .NET availability.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/) to package your application. It has action to detect .NET described here: http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/docs/installbuilder-7.0.3-userguide.html#autodetectDotNetFramework