# How do I add Platform Update 1 to my bootstrapper?

Tags: deployment, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine, bootstrapper, platform-update-1

I have been playing around with the new `StateMachine` workflow that has been added to Windows Workflow as part of [Platform Update 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/18/microsoft-net-framework-4-platform-update-1.aspx) ([see also](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2478063)). I now want to look at installing what I've created and therefore need to make sure my bootstrapper is up-to-date. In the future, I will be moving to WIX but right now, for the purposes of prototyping, I'm just using a regular Setup and Deployment project and its bootstrap support.

The list of standard pre-requisites does not include the PU1 as an option. Therefore, how can I add support for it?

**Update**
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project) on StackOverflow regarding custom prerequisites, which led me to [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx), which led me to creating my own pre-requisite.  However, I got a new error about mismatched framework requirements. I suspect I need to pick apart the multi-targeting support and the existing .NET framework prerequisite package to see how to make a new prerequisite that will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a stab at creating my own bootstrapper packages for this. The results are [here to download](http://bit.ly/h1Pcto). Note that these are entirely untested and provided as-is - use at your own risk. However, feedback is welcome. Hopefully Microsoft will provide an official solution.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to detect if the .NET Framework Platform Update 1 is installed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/04/29/how-to-detect-if-the-net-framework-platform-update-1-is-installed.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

is the Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1 - Runtime Update (KB2478063) what you are looking for? See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e85a2f1b-031c-419c-95b2-0610e90bafd7&displaylang=en) for the download.

Comment: No - my question already has links regarding that part. I have the runtime update - I am looking to add it as a bootstrapped pre-requisite for my deployment.

Comment: I have added custom VS prerequisites but it was a long time ago. As I recall it wasn't hard once I figured out what to do but I don't recall the details.

Comment: I got the pre-requisite added but I encountered another error. I'm working on that right now. Unfortunately, there isn't much info on the exit codes and command line parameters for the installers - this may prove to be a stumbling block. Also, I need to find a decent way to detect whether the PU is installed or not.

Comment: To detect if Platform Update 1 is installed  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NET Framework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\
• .NETFramework, Version=v4.0.1
• .NETFramework, Version-v4.0.1, Profile=Client