# Visual studio setup project which installs prerequisites but does not contain them

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 3.5 for my project.

I'm trying to create a setup project which will also install .NET Framework 3.5 and a custom app (WinPcap) as prerequisites for my application.

I don't want to include .NET + WinPcap in setup.exe as a standalone installer.
Instead, I want to specify a local relative path for each prerequisite (like \Prerequisites\DotNet.exe) in which the installations will be contained.

This way I can still distribute my app in a 'standalone' if I wish and a minimal setup.

I've tried searching through this site and the web but I couldn't figure how to get the behavior I want.

Some guidance would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Visual Studio. The package either has prerequisites or it doesn't have them.

A solution would be to create custom prerequisites which are downloaded from an URL. This way you can distribute a smaller installer and the prerequisites are downloaded only when needed.

Perhaps this will help you configure the prerequisites: [Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project)

Another solution is to build 2 separate packages: one with prerequisites and one without them.