# Installing Acrobat Flash with windows installer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I'm trying to install Adobe Flash Player with my app installer , but with no success .
I prepared the Adobe Flash Player as prerequest to visual studio but also with no success .
If there is a cool way to do that , any tutorial , link , ...

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help: [Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project)