# Registry search and custom actions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

I need to install Flash player with my application MSI. So I did these steps:

1. Go to Launch conditions editor.
2. Right click Search target machine.
3. Add registry search
4. In the property window of the registry search I wrote:

   - Property - FLASHPLAYERREGISTRYVALUE
   - RegKey - SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\CurrentVersion
   - Root - vsdrrHKLM
   - Value - 10,3,181,34
5. Right click Lauch conditions
6. Add Launch condition
7. In the property window of the condition I set:

   - Contidion - FLASHPLAYERREGISTRYVALUE (the search registry property name)
   - InstallUrl - Flash player installation url
   - Message - ...

The installer returns false all the time. I mean it says no flash player installed although the key allready exists in the registry and it tries to install Flash player .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install other software with your package you can use [prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz%28VS.80%29.aspx). Here is a discussion which may help you: [Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project)

A better detection criteria is checking the version for this file:

```
[SystemFolder]Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32.dll
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should rather use:

- Property - FLASHPLAYERREGISTRYVALUE
- RegKey -
  **SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer**
- Root - HKLM
- Value - **CurrentVersion**

then the FLASHPLAYERREGISTRYVALUE should resolve to "10,3,181,34" which is the contents of "CurrentVersion" registry value in your case.