# VB2010: Visual Studio Installer add other installer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, installshield

Triying to use the built in Visual Studio 2010 to install a couple of files and after that is done to run another installer package (3rd Party Installation Wizard).

Comment: Two installer packages?  My pet peeve. . .

Comment: If I knew exactly what the other installer did then I might of done it all in one package.

Comment: Why not add the second installer as a prerequisite? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project

Comment: Tried it and managed to add the prerequisite to the list, but have a couple of issues with it. First, the 3rd Party Installation is InstallSheild 5.10.130.0, not exactly sure how to add that to the product.xml file. I added just the setup.exe in the xml and when the program complied it only included the setup.exe file. I hand copied the rest of the files and when the installer runs it gives the error: "unable to find installation languages"

Answer (score 1):

I tried that the "normal" way and didn't succeed. Installers can't be mixed, run simultaneously.

What I did, though, was to make another application that run two installers, one after another. My application first, then SQL Server Express. It worked. Eventual problem is, if second installer fail, it wont rollback the first installation. It was something I could live with.

My setup application then looks like this (pseudocode):

```
proces1 = Run MyApp.msi
Wait for proces1 to complete
proces2 = Run 3thPartyApp.msi
Wait for proces2 to complete
```

You can get return codes from processes you run from .net, so you know if anything failed.

Finally, you can use selfextracting archive to package everything into one, easy to distribute exe file.

Comment: This is probably the most straight forward idea. You would just have to rollback the first installation explicitly.

Comment: How did you call the other installer from the Setup Wizard?

Comment: @Rick: Not from the setup wizard. From your application, run first setup process then after it exited, run second one. Look at my edits.

Comment: Was hoping to have the exe in one single file.

Comment: Should I create another solution with just the code to install both MSIs?

Comment: @Rick: I have both project (msi setup project and new project)  in the same solution.