# Add another exe file in my setup file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation

I have created a Windows setup file for my Windows project in Visual Studio 2010. This setup file is running properly and installed the software in the computer. But for running this software I need another exe file to run. I want to add this external exe file into my setup project so that when my software will install the other software will be installed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add another file that will be deployed on the target machine when installing you can go to your project, **File Setup** tab, right click on the folder that you want to add the file to (eg. **Application Folder**), in the context menu click **Add - File** and browse to the file that you want to add. It can be any external file from your computer.

That file will get installed along with your application.

**Edit** - To get to the File Setup tab right click on your project in the solution explorer and select View - File System.

**Edit 2** - In order to add a custom prerequisite to your setup project have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project).

Comment: thanx for this, but i m not understanding where u are saying for adding the files. can u please say me this in briefly. Please it is very urgent.

Comment: sorry , but it is not working, the external exe is not installing after installation of my setup file.

Comment: @Aditya, if the other file is a setup package that you also want ti install, have a look at a bootstrapper: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

Comment: yes another file is also a exe file, nd i also want to install it with my setup file.

Comment: @Aditya, You can up vote the answers that helped you and mark as accepted the one that worked for you, if any. For more info see here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: hiii thanx for ur help, r u a .net developer.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're using a "Setup Project" (vs. InstallShield, for example).

It sounds like you want a "custom action":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbd7cck3.aspx
- http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/
  <= Look for "calling an executable as a custom action"

Comment: i have created a setup file using vs2010. And another is a exe file which i want to install with my setup file.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010, I had 3 Projects outputting 2 DLLs & 1 EXE, and a 4th Project as Setup Project. To add the DLLs & EXE in setup.exe file, this is how I did it,

Right Click on your Setup Project,
Right Click->View->File System->Application Folder

In the Application Folder pane, Right Click->Add->Project Output

Select the required project from the drop down Project list and select "Primary Output".

That should be it.