# Can VS 2010 Setup Include MCR as prerequisite?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, installation, matlab-deployment

I have a project that I'm trying to build an installer for using a Visual Studio setup project. I'm wondering if there is a way to get the MatLab Compiler Runtime included as a prerequisite. Right now I have to include the MCRSetup.exe and have the user run that first and then my installer. Not too onerous but I was just wondering if there is a way to make it all happen in one step, so that the MCR stuff gets installed the same way that .NET and the C++ runtime libs get installed.

I did try going to the prerequisites tab but there is no choice for selecting the MCR (not that I expected one). I also tried adding the MCRInstaller.exe to my Application Folder. This almost works (much to my surprise). The MCR Installer runs automatically and appears to be the last step. However, it fails before it gets very far because it senses that another installer is running (which is my project that launched it) and the user is instructed to quit that installer first. I'm sure my users will find this confusing and I was hoping to make it a little more seamless.

Comment: CharithJ below linked to a question on how to add custom prerequisites to your installer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project

Comment: Thanks. Originally when I clicked the link it too me to a different site that wasn't helpful not it appears to link to another SO question. It's still not clear that this is going to work with the MCR and VC++ but I'll pursue it again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I found the one reply I got informative it didn't really solve the problem. I'm going to have to set as the answer that it can't (or maybe shouldn't) be done. Trying the 2nd radio button in set up was informative though. When you do that the installer creates folders for .NET and C++ restributables. This is good to know if I have customers that don't want to be on the Internet when installing.

Unfortunately, in addition to the MCR installer failure I alluded to in my question, the VC++ installer is somewhat problematic also. When I go to install a new version, the VC++ installer actually wants to run a reinstall. I don't understand this at all. I could see it OFFERING to do an uninstall. Since I will be distributing two programs that rely on .NET, VC++ and the MCR, I have to conclude I shouldn't make the installers all inclusive. The uninstall/reinstall is just too confusing and needlessly lengthy. The way .NET is handled seamlessly behind the scenes is perfect but VC++ and the MCR installers don't appear to support the same methodology.

I'm just going to have the final users do three installs, while not very elegant I'm pretty sure this will result in the fewest questions when the time comes to install an upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Prerequisites_in_Setup.aspx).

[image]
[image]

You can copy the setup and browse to that location as mention in the second screen.

Or look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project).