# Adding .Net framework updates to a setup project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, setup-project

I have a setup project which, as a prerequisite, requires the .Net 4 framework installed locally on the target machine. I specify the install location for prerequisites as "download prerequistes from the same location as my application" resulting in the dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe being added to the installer (since the target machines we install to are not connect to a network, i.e. standalone).

I'd also like the installer to recognise it needs to install any [updates](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=608) of the .Net 4 framework to the standalone target machine if required. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what updates are required, the simplest way to do it is probably just to create new bootstrapper packages for the standalone updates, and add them as additional prerequisites.  There's more info on that here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've also seen this which my question is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project