# How to create the asp.net web setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-setup-project

I have a Asp.net application which I want to make it easy to depoly in client machine by click the .ext or .msi file.

Then I found the "web setup project" in vs.

However I have no idea how to make it.

In my case,my application need .Net 4.

And after the app is deployed I have to modify something in the web.config which I want to gather through the install wizard.

Also I need to do some clean work after deploy(modify some files).

So I wonder if my requirement is possible using "web setup project",and how to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can modify files during install only through [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So you will need to write custom code which does what you need. Regarding .NET Framework 4, it can be added as a [prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project).

If you want an easier solution, you can try a commercial setup authoring tool: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

For example, Advanced Installer has a dedicated project type for ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,We can make Custom Actions(Framing Connection during installation ,Consuming WCF service for Web App)to .msi file during installation.
If you want to have more clear picture about this refer my articles.

This is to create or change Connection string along with setup creation for Windows Application

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/446121/Adding-connection-String-During-Installation

In this creating setup file for Web App which consumes WCF service

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/477202/SetUp-file-Creation-for-Web-Application-which-Cons