# Custom prerequisites

Tags: c#, winforms

I created the setup file using Visual Studio 2010 successfully, but now I need to include third party software and this software should be installed with my setup file and also need to check before installation if it is exists already on vendors machine if not, then do the installation. Can any help me of this??

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation and break down each question?  For instance, what do you mean be 'third party software'? A .dll file?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project

Comment: ofcourse,for example Skype,Adobe reador,VLS player,and so...,so i need to install those kind of  third party softwares with my Windows form application setup file on the clients machine.

Comment: @Micah Armantrout Yes,it might be duplication i could not get correct answer which i want,also there no clear expolanation,like how to add whole package to software and towards installation??

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good start : the bootstrapper  [link](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg). Also look at this for the how to 
of creating bootstrapper package [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx)

[Edit]

You can download the bootstrapper form [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1567). And it will work for VS 2010, but you need to manually move the generated files to the new bootstrapper location (in my case, 64-bit Windows 7, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages).

If you have VS open, you will have to restart it in order for your prerequisite to show up in the list.

Comment: But there is no bootstraper generator for VS 2010,apart, i tried as link2 two,but no use :)

Comment: The first link and the link to download the bootstrapper does not work anymore