# Visual Studio Installer To Set Application, Framework And The Third Party Tool Setup

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have completed working on a C#.NET Project on .NET framework 4 client profile.
Now this application so as to run at the client end require two things to be installed earlier
1) .NET Framework
2) Third Party Tool

My application generates some documents which is then using a batch command calling and passing paramters to the third party tool .exe file i generate the final output. But my client is hesitating or scared to install so many things to his computer so i was requested to incorporate all this setup to one  visual studio installer. I went through many sites and found the way to get the framework incorporated to my installer but i am not able to find a way to incorporate the third party tool setup to my installer.

1) If there is a way through Visual Studio Then kindly suggest the sets or share the related article
2) If the same can be achieved using any other tool then suggest the same both open source and paid once

Answer (score 0):

You should add the third party tool as a prerequisite to your VS installer setup project. Check the [Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project) thread.

Also, you can try to use any paid tool for creating Windows Installer based setups (like InstallShield, Advanced Installer, etc.) which has support for adding prerequisites.