# Is it possible to run another installer while installing something in Windows?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msvc12

I have an .msi installer developed using wix that installs some dlls in a directory on the file system. Some of these dlls have dependency on Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. I am wondering that is it possible to install that run time (downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) during my installer's installation process? - that is while the .msi installer is running and copying dlls, it will install the MSVC run time at the same time for the user.

I want to know if this is possible.. If it is, is this generally a good or bad practice? Should it be enough to just copy the MSVCP120.dll and MSVCR120.dll along with all other dlls? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***VC++ Runtime***: The Visual C++ runtime can be installed via [merge modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-components-by-using-merge-modules?view=msvc-160) ([basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/merge-modules)) inside the MSI ([there are some limitations with later versions of the runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51423249/129130)) or as an executable on its own (**`vcredist_x86.exe`** or **`vcredist_x64.exe`**), generally installed before your main MSI ([latest C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)).

***Setup.exe***: You can bundle such a runtime installer inside a **`setup.exe`** made with WiX's Burn feature ([Hello Burn example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071758/129130) - it is a bootstrapper, chainer, launcher - runs installs in sequence) or a similar feature in [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) ([suite projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212599/129130)), [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) or [other packaging tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). Some resources: [More on Burn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451051/129130) and [Making setup.exe launchers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470977/129130).

***Universal CRT***: As stated in this answer, it is recommended to use the **`vcredist_x86.exe`** or **`vcredist_x64.exe`** installers instead of the merge modules due to the "Universal CRT" components not being installed properly with the merge modules. "Universal CRT" relates to Visual C++ support for Universal Apps built for the [Universal Windows Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform).

***Single File Copy***: Please avoid copying single files to the location application folder. This is important in order to be able to rely on system-wide security fixes for the C++ runtime (coming down from Windows Update or installed in other ways).

---

***Links:***

- [**The latest supported Visual C++ downloads**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
- [Installshield, WiX Burn, Advanced Installer, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470977/129130)
- [Detect Visual C++ Runtime installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639128/129130)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I think I am going to go with the bootstrapper approach. Regarding checking if the run time is already installed, I came across one of your posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638587/wix-per-user-installer-to-detect-the-visual-c-2015-redistributable, which is also very helpful.

Comment: I wrote that a few years ago, and it might be helpful, but it is also quite a mess. I didn't find any super reliable approaches back then - usually that means there is a better way, but I am not aware of one at this stage. Perhaps there is a API-call from Windows itself that can report it? There probably is - or maybe WMI / Powershell? Maybe I should check and update the answer. Will have to do that later. Maybe check my experimental ["Jumpgate"](https://installdude.com/jumpgate.php) for more help resources. [Main site](https://installdude.com/).