# Can you choose a custom prerequisite path through visual studio installer projects?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022

I have a VB.NET WinForms application. I've created the installer wizard for it using the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Extension for VS2022" extension.

I've added a .NET 5 prerequisite through the dialog box, but I've encountered a problem. My users are not so tech-savvy, and when the prompt to install .NET comes, it redirects to the dotnet installation page, there are lots of release notes, x86, x64, yada yada. They probably wouldn't understand.

Is there anyway to make the installer use a custom link, so that I could use the direct download link from MSFT's site instead?


Edit: I've read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project

 
I'm not trying to bootstrap custom prerequisites. I want it to install .NET automatically without the user having to find the installer from the page it opens, download it, install it, then rerun the installer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project)

Comment: Hi @BogdanMitrache, I've edited my post to reflect what I was trying to ask through this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem by running the `setup.exe` file that is generated.

The `setup.msi` file does not automatically install prerequisites while `setup.exe` does.
From what I have read it has something to do with `msiexec.exe` not being able to run multiple instances of one another.