# How can I add SQL Server 2019 Express as a prerequisite in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, prerequisites

I am using a Visual Studio Setup project. How can I add SQL Server 2019 Express as a prerequisite?

It includes only SQL Server 2012 Express. But I also need to implement SQL Server 2019 Express.

[image]

Comment: Does this help you? [Adding Custom prerequsites to visual studio setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project)

Comment: Seems like you could download the SQL Server installer and create a package manifest for it (it has command line options)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that SQL express is part of, and can be installed along side Visual Studio.

If you want to use SQL express (in place of local db), and I STRONG recommend that you do use + install SQL express?

Then you have to go get, and download and install SQL express. And while you doing that, you might as well go ahead and install SQL management studio. (and the express version these days is rather nice - even includes the sql profiler tools).

So, you can't choose, nor have Visual Studio install say Excel, Word, power-point, SQL server or some accounting package, or some PDF viewer?

If you need and want these other applications?

You have to go get them, and install them - such installs of such software is 100% outside the realm of Visual Studio and what it has for options to be installed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have install. Visual Studio 2022. Sql Server Express 2019 Latest version. And managment studio latest version. But i cant see any option for this. What else can i try? I need to create an installion which automatically installs sql. That's why i need to add it as prerequisite.